# Display large rich text field values on to the web in XPages

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a rich text field storing comma separated numbers (large numbers from 11111 to 99999 with three character prefix - so xxx11111, xxx11112 etc). I am using the appendText property and in the document I noticed that after around 16KB another rich text field with the same name is created.

But when I display this information on the web:

```
<xp:inputRichText id="inputRichText1" readonly="true" value="#{doc.RichTextField}">
</xp:inputRichText>
```

it's only displaying upto xxx16351. What am I missing here?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you open the document in notes client (with a form)? Do you get a message "Document has too many paragraphs"? How do you have created the document? With a XPage or an agent?

Comment: Thanks Sven for your comment. Yes I can open the document in Notes client. The document has already been created, so I just ran LS code (using customer specific logic) to generate the numbers. I am using appendText property of a rich text item to add the data as normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to alter your approach. What should work is [Tim's MIME](http://xmage.gbs.com/blog.nsf/D6Plinks/TTRY-8NKTPN) usage. So instead of RichText you write into a MIME field and the Domino engine takes care of size and rendering.

In any case, speak after me:
There is no RichText on the web, it is a ghost of Christmas past, there is only MIME.

Let us know how it goes

Comment: Thanks Steven (and Tim!), this makes sense. I will look into it and keep you guys posted (although I am going away on a holiday for a month and a half, so the response might be a bit delayed!). I especially like the ghost of Christmas past part - thanks for the entertainment.

Answer (score 1):

Is it only displaying the content from the first rich text field? I suspect that the value binding to fields will only retrieve from the first NotesItem with that name, rather than aggregating all NotesItems with that name.

Comment: Thanks Paul - That's what I thought at first, but the data is spanning across roughly 3 and a half fields!